# Is it possible to join two query result with PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to `JOIN` 2 tables (lets say `User` & `Order` table) for reporting module in my web app.

The problems are:

1. The `User` table is **located on the different server & different
   DBMS** from the `Order` table. Technically it is a different system, so the `User` table is located on SQL Server DB, meanwhile the `Order` table is located on MySQL DB.
2. **I couldn't use SQL Server's Linked Server** because my company policy doesn't allow it. So, I coudn't `JOIN` them directly with SQL code. They want me to use Web Service instead of linked server.
3. The result of `JOIN` operation from those tables has a large number of rows (maybe more than 10,000 rows because the data aimed for reporting). So, I think it was a horrible thing to mapping them using Web Service.

So I came up with this:

I collected 2 query result from different models and join them with my app code (I'm using PHP with CodeIgniter) :

```
// First result
$userData = $this->userModel->getAllUser();

// Second result
$orderData = $this->orderModel->getAllOrder();
```

The `$userData` contains all user entities with the following columns:

```
[UserId, Username, Address, PhoneNumber, etc..]
```

And the `$orderData` contains all order entities with the following columns:

```
[OrderId, UserId, Date, etc..]
```

But is it possible to join those two query results in PHP / CodeIgniter?

How about the performance regarding the large amount of data?

Should I just use Web Service as suggested or there's another solution to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible to read from the MsSQL database and insert to a MySQL temp table, then join that to your the MySQL table you are interested in?

Comment: Oh ya, seems it's possible... I got an array from SQL Server query then insert it into MySQL table. Should I loop for each row and insert them one-by-one or how?

Comment: Depends on the quantities. Probably easiest to loop around building up batches to insert (so you insert several hundred rows at a time) as this will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to think about:

1. Do you actually need to return *all* user and order records in one single go
2. Do you actually want to return *all* rows for these two types of record
3. Would you be better off with a Report module for these report queries?
4. Would plain SQL syntax be a smarter move than trying to shim this into existence with the CodeIgniter "Active Record" (renamed Query Builder in 3.0)
5. Is `JOIN` really so bad? It is not a `UNION`, you want the data to be related.

I would recommend you limit your data returns, `SELECT` only the fields you actually require, make a new Report model to avoid trying to mess up your generic models and do this with raw SQL.

Complicated things get all the more complicated when you try too hard to stick to rules like "1 table = 1 model" and "User::getAllFoos + controller processing > Report::getMonthlyOrderStats()".

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
1. Yes, because I need to export all report summary to Excel.

2. No, because I just need the Users who have any Orders.

3. Yes, it's better to have a separate module. 

4. Yes, of course plain SQL would be great. But, I couldn't get a direct SQL because the table was separated between diferent DBMS.

5. No, it's not. But the problem is not about SQL JOIN performance itself. The problem is how to perform JOIN without direct SQL?

Comment: Oh. Then map an array of user IDs and itterate through things. If you literally cannot use SQL to solve this because the different servers are different engines then foreaches are your only real option here.